# iPhone - How to post and get xml data to server？

Tags: ios, xml

I want to get xml string from url "http://test.php?value=xxx",here xxx shall be in XML format,for example:`<request><command>test</command></request>`.After I post this,the server will give me a result with xml string.But i don't know how to do that.Anyone has a solution?Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.raywenderlich.com/30445/afnetworking-crash-course

That website gives you a step by step exactly what you need with AFNetworking.  The question you are asking is very vague.  If you get more specific then I can give direct code.  Otherwise that crash course website is very informative.